# view custom message in product page by category id

Tags: magento-1, custom-options, product-view, category-products, category-view

How do I **display** a **message** (ex. AVAILABLE IN 30 DAY) in product page only for a specific category id (98, 100 and 101)?

I've created

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="sedia">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('chair') ?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

in view.phtml, and

```
<?php
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
?>

<?php if ($catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds(); == '100')) ?>
        <div class="trentagg">
            <p>AVAILABLE IN 30 DAY</p>
        </div>

<?php endif;
?>
```

in chair.phtml but it's not working.
Thanks

Comment: let me know whether your product has been assigned to  multiple categories?

Comment: hi @fossati whether you got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code as shown in view.phtml

```
 <?php 
    $_product = $this->getProduct(); 
    $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach($categoryIds as $id) {
      $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
      echo  $cat->getId()."<br>";
      echo  $cat->getName()."<br>";
      if($cat->getId() == '98')
      {
         echo "AVAILABLE IN 30 DAY";
      }
    }
    ?>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]